# How to run QtQuick application from CLI?

Tags: cmake, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick, ubuntu-20.04

My application is practically just the QtQuick template for CMake generated by Qt Creator.

Works great when launched from IDE, but when I compile and run in CLI I get:

```
$ ./test
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
```

Is there now some package missing from my system Qt (Ubuntu 20.04) or should I set some path to somewhere?

Naturally the end user shouldn't need to set any library paths when running my application.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that I needed to:

`$ sudo apt install qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-window2`